# Node.JS event error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

i have just moved server to Amazon EC2.

Node.JS was working fine before but since moved, it gives me an event error which im not really sure whats going on.

i run command **netstat -nlp** to see if the ports number are opened.

the ports number are opened (8080 and 8181).

its giving an error on line *89:7* which the following:

```
https.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('HTTPS Server listening at port: ' + port);
});
```

[image]

Comment: have you specified hostname correctly.

Comment: i have! do you know how to stop port number (8080/8181) running automatically

Comment: I don't have idea about what you asked.

you can try to check the if there exists a process running on node.
try 'ps aux| grep :node'
May be you see previous instance of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EADDRINUSE` means "error - address in use". You need to stop the service already listening on that address (read: IP and port combination). You can discover the pid and name of that service with `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof -Pan -i tcp | grep -E '(8080|8181)'
```

i.e. on my local machine:

```
$ sudo lsof -Pan -i tcp | grep -E '(51235)'
java      12413   andy  669u  IPv4 1088377      0t0  TCP *:51235 (LISTEN)
```

The pid (process ID) is the second number - in this case, `12413`. This can be used to terminate the process.

Use `kill 12413` to terminate that process. Another `lsof` shows there's nothing listening on that port, as it's been killed:

```
$ sudo lsof -Pan -i tcp | grep -E '(51235)'
<nothing here>
$
```

It may be that you've already got another service running (HTTP proxies tend to listen on 8080), or possibly another version of your same app. You may have to decide whether to use different ports or move the current service if there's a proxy running there.

Comment: how do you kill / terminate the port number?

Comment: `kill X` where X is the PID of the process, not the port number. It's not possible to pass a port number to `kill`, which is why I use `lsof` to find the PID :)

Comment: thanks so much :). i managed to kill the service, but how do i start the server again with the port number?

Comment: If there was a service already running that you killed it may start again at boot time. If there's nothing listening on the port you need (as you've killed/fixed it), you can start your node app as you would normally and it should be able to bind to the address. If you want to restart the service you killed restarting the box is probably easiest.

Comment: the port numbers are already in the instance service. (8080) `/etc/init.d/serverjs1` and (8181) `/etc/init.d/serverjs2`. whats the command to run the service1 and service2? `sudo service start serverjs2`

Comment: (depends on systemd vs systemv, but) that is how to start a systemv service, yes.